# No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector decodeFromPercentageEscapeString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface

Don't know what is wrong with the code.
Error - No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector decodeFromPercentageEscapeString

```
@interface ReviewViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, ReviewDelegate> {

NSMutableArray* _arrayData;
int _reviewCount;
int _requestCount;
int _returnCount;
int _totalRowCount;
UIRefreshControl* _refreshControl; }
```

This is where it gives me the error:

```
        NSString* review1 = [dict[@"review"] stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
        NSString* review2 = [review1 stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];


        review1 = [review2 decodeFromPercentEscapeString:review2]; //where the error occurs


        [cell.labelDescription setText:review1];


        CGSize size = [cell.labelDescription sizeOfMultiLineLabel];
        CGRect frame = cell.labelDescription.frame;
        cell.labelDescription.frame = frame;
```

Comment: `decodeFromPercentEscapeString:` is apparently an old 3rd party category.  It has been supplanted by several `stringBy..` methods, if you actually bother to check the documentation for NSString.

Comment: NSString doesn't have a public method called `decodeFromPercentEscapeString:`. Nor does it have a method called `stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText`, so you should be getting the same error on those lines as well. Are you using any class categories?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you copy/pasted this code from is wrong.

There is no method on `NSString` called `decodeFromPercentEscapeString` which is why the compiler is providing that warning.

You'll either need to implement it yourself, or also copy the category on `NSString` that was probably also included in the example.